# QT QtConcurrent run with overloaded class function

Tags: c++, qt, overloading

I have a class that I use to compress files into different formats. I'm trying to use QtConcurrent to run the compression in the background. With this I have two functions:

1. Takes file path as a string and compression format
2. Takes a vector of file paths and compression format

Issue is I'm getting issues with QtConcurrent not knowing which overloaded function to use. I read [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762460/how-to-use-qtconcurrentrun-with-overloaded-function) which showed using static_cast to explicitly state which method to use. I'm getting stuck with the syntax though since my functions are class functions and not static methods. Can I even use static_cast for this considering these are not static methods?

**How I'm calling run:**

```
CompressFile compressor(&m_sysLog); 
QVector<QString> files;     
CompressFormat format((CompressFormat)pMsgCast->get_format()); 
QtConcurrent::run(&compressor, &CompressFile::compress, files, format);
```

**Header for compression class**

```
class CompressFile : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

...

bool compress(QString strFileName, CompressFormat format);            
bool compress(QVector<QString> strFileList, CompressFormat format);

...
}
```

If I remove one of the compress functions it compiles so I know I've narrowed my issue down to this.

> FileCompressor.cpp:100:74: note:   types ‘T (Class::)(Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, Param5)const’ and ‘bool (CompressFile::)(QString, CompressFormat)’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers
>   FileCompressor.cpp:100:74: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function ‘& CompressFile::compress’

Comment: You *should* be able to use `static_cast`.  Try `QtConcurrent::run(&compressor, static_cast<bool(CompressFile::*)(QVector<QString>, CompressFormat)>(&CompressFile::compress), files, format)`.

Comment: That worked! My syntax was way off so thanks. If you make that a post I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment, you can use a `static_cast` to disambiguate between the various overloads...

```
QtConcurrent::run(&compressor,
                  static_cast<bool(CompressFile::*)(QVector<QString>, CompressFormat)>(&CompressFile::compress),
                  files,
                  format);
```